# jQuery calculate new date from seconds of current date

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, time

The current date is `2015-07-30 06:00` and `41786` seconds have passed.. how do i get the new date and time in the current date format?

```
    var timeString = "2015-07-30 06:00";
                // start time
                var startTime = new Date(timeString);
                // add duration to the start time
var duration = 41786;
                startTime.setSeconds(startTime.getSeconds() + duration);
```

When i alert `startTime` i don't get the new date after the seconds have passed.
How do i solve?

Comment: Not sure what you are expecting when there are no seconds in string so therefore they are 0. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: works fine here: `Thu Jul 30 2015 17:36:26 GMT+0100`

Comment: from the date `2015-07-30 06:00`  + 41786 .. i want to display a new date in that format.

Comment: Try to use timeString = "2015-07-30T06:00"

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `getTime()`:

```
startTime.setTime(startTime.getTime() + (41786 * 1000))
```

Comment: not working i get `Thu Jul 30 2015 06:00:41 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)`  returned

Comment: 41786 is seconds btw

Comment: You can use that anyway, just transform seconds to miliseconds